# Heat Exchanger- the calculation of q

Tags: heat-transfer

What is the heat transfer difference between parallel flow and counter-flow heat exchanger?
Are different equations used to calculate q?

Comment: Check out Heat Transfer by Simonson...

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods: The logarithmic mean and the NUT efficiency methods. Get info about those methods and you'll be able to calculate Q.